# How to invoke Load_form function without using button

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, system.timers.timer

I am trying to create a GUI that shows small 3 images on the app. When there is a new image in the folder, the new image has to be on the right
side of the imageBoxes. In order to do that, I am using a timer to invoke Load_Form function. The interval is 1000ms. However after some time (
approximately 3:20 min), the program gives an exception "Out of memory" or "Parameter is not valid". Is there another way to update imageboxes automatically( when there is
new image, update it)? The code is here, thank you in advance:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
  using System.Timers;

 namespace test1
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
        string actCode = null;
        string pathLogNames = @"D:\LOG\Right";
        string[] imPaths;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //timer1.Start();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    string[] getFiles(string path, string text, string fileExtension)
    {
        try
        {
            string searchingText = text;
            searchingText = "*" + text + "*";
            string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchingText, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            List<string> filesList = new List<string>(filesArray);
            List<string> newFilesList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in filesList)
            {
                if (file.Contains(fileExtension) == true)
                {
                    newFilesList.Add(file);
                }
            }
            string[] files = newFilesList.ToArray();
            return files;
        }
        catch
        {
            string[] files = new string[0];
            return files;
        }

    }

  

    string[] viewerPaths;
    int pathsNumber;
    Image actImage;
    Image actImage1;
    Image actImage2;
    //int actIndex;
    double imageDefaultZoom;
    public bool mouseFlag = false;
    //Point startPoint = new Point();

    public void setPaths(string[] paths, double defZoom)
    {
        viewerPaths = paths;
        pathsNumber = viewerPaths.Length;
        imageDefaultZoom = defZoom;
        int total = viewerPaths.Length;
        if (pathsNumber > 0)
        {
            actImage = Image.FromFile(viewerPaths[total - 3]);
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(actImage);
            Image i = resizeImage(b, new Size(100, 100));
            pictureBox1.Image = i;

            actImage1 = Image.FromFile(viewerPaths[total - 2]);
            Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(actImage1);
            Image i1 = resizeImage(b1, new Size(100, 100));
            pictureBox2.Image = i1;

            actImage2 = Image.FromFile(viewerPaths[total - 1]);
            Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(actImage2);
            Image i2 = resizeImage(b2, new Size(100, 100));
            pictureBox3.Image = i2;
        }
    }

    private static System.Drawing.Image resizeImage(System.Drawing.Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        //Get the image current width  
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        //Get the image current height  
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;
        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;
        //Calulate  width with new desired size  
        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        //Calculate height with new desired size  
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;
        //New Width  
        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        //New Height  
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        // Draw image with new width and height  
        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();
        return (System.Drawing.Image)b;
    }
    private void onChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Dispose();
        imPaths = getFiles(pathLogNames, actCode, ".tif");
        setPaths(imPaths, 0.5);
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        imPaths = getFiles(pathLogNames, actCode, ".tif");
        setPaths(imPaths, 0.5);
        
        }
    }
 }


}
```

Comment: you may consider [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0) to catch the event of a new file arrived, instead of run a stopwatch

Comment: The garbage collector won't run often enough to keep you out of the trouble caused by the missing Dispose() calls in setPaths().  For actImage, b and the old pictureBox.Image if it isn't null, times 3.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the comment but when I called Dispose() method in sethPaths(), my program did not work. I mean I cannot see windows form, but I did not get any error message.

Comment: @dba thank you, i will try to implement and let you know.

Comment: @dba it worked better than timers. But still there may be a problem regarding memory resource.

Comment: @OguzKahraman can you describe the Problems you are facing here?

Comment: @dba, when a changing happens in the folder (moving a new image), process memory is constantly increasing per image. I may face the same error ("Out of Memory") after some time. I need to clear memory somehow but I do not know yet.

Comment: Hard to say , w/o seeing you implementation. Can you show the filesystemwatcher part?

Comment: @dba I added filesystemwatcher in design section, I wrote the path and event I selected onChanged event.  I edited my code after including onChanged event.

Comment: Okay, I've rebuilt your app, I guess you miss the `actImage.Dispose();` to free up reference to the file

Comment: I uploaded the tets-App to [Github](https://github.com/dbalogh78/FileSystemWatchSample)

Comment: Oh that is great, thank you so much, it works constantly.